# Do we need to provide LIMIT in soql query while using REST API?

Tags: python-2.7, rest, salesforce

I was using simple-salesforce library to query the salesforce through REST API but getting query timeout error. I have not added the LIMIT keyword in the query as I thought salesforce will automatically only return 2000 result and after that, it will provide nextRecordURL for other 2000 records.

My Current implementation looks like this,

```
json_response = self.sf_api_instance.query_all_custom(query)
parent_mapper = SalesForceMapper(json_response, field_mapping=field_mapping) 
self.send_data(parent_mapper, object_type)
is_done = json_response.pop("done", False)
next_records_url = json_response.pop("nextRecordsUrl", '')
if json_response["records"]:
     self.processed_Ids[object_type] = json_response["records"][0]["Id"] 
     self.memorize(self.processed_Ids, self.username)
while True:
   if not is_done:
      json_response = self.sf_api_instance.query_more(next_records_url, True) 
      parent_mapper = SalesForceMapper(json_response, field_mapping=field_mapping) 
      self.send_data(parent_mapper, object_type)
      is_done = json_response.pop("done", False)
      next_records_url = json_response.pop("nextRecordsUrl", '')
   else:
      break
```

So is my understanding is right or I need to provide LIMIT in every query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely because your query isn't selective and taking a very long time to run.  Follow the directions [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=How-to-make-my-SOQL-query-selective&language=en_US&type=1) to make your query selective.  In short try not to use negative criteria in your where clause like <> or NOT IN and use indexed values.  When you do that the query will execute quickly and not time out.